# string incorrectly translated by ado

Tags: sql, vbscript, asp-classic, ado, codepages

I have a database with collation SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS.  In that database I have a varchar field.  There is a row in that database with the string "ó" (single character 243 in codepage 1252).  I have a simple ASP page that sets the codepage to 65001, reads that row (using adodb), and sends it out to the browser.  Everything works fine if the "current language for non-unicode programs" is set to English.  If I change that to Russian and browse to the page I see "o".  I can set a breakpoint in the server side asp page and it appears that ado is returning "o" instead of "ó".

Why does the "current language for non-unicode programs" matter?  The database has the data and is configured for the proper code page.  I thought that internally ADO and VBScript stored everything as unicode.  It appears that somewhere the string is being converted to the codepage specified in "current language for non-unicode programs" but even that doesn't make much sense as I would expect to see "?" instead of "o" (but I don't really understand what handles the conversion from one codepage to another and what rules it uses).

I understand that changing the column to nvarchar may help but that doesn't explain why this is happening.

(edit)
I understand why "ó" is being converted to "o".  Windows Best Fit http://www.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/MICSFT/WindowsBestFit/bestfit1251.txt

Still trying to figure out how to get the codepage 1252 string out of SQL and into VBScript without loss.

Comment: Here's example code:
http://www.blogtrog.com/code.aspx?id=c435803f-157d-468d-a0e2-449b03877a56

Comment: It appears that this just isn't possible.  Can anyone confirm that?
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/904803
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/234748